# Getting data to only show within a date range using javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to show some data within calendar dates. I giving it a start date and an end date. I only want it to show within those dates. I have been trying to do this but I cannot seem to make it work right. I thought I had it but was wrong.

```
var objData = [];
var month = [ "january","february","march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "October", "november", "december"];
var d = new Date( );
var currDate = d.getDate();
var currMonth = d.getMonth();
var currYear = d.getFullYear();
var currPromoIndex;

for (var i =0; i < obj.length; i++)
{
    var start = obj[i].dateRange[0];
    var end = obj[i].dateRange[1];
    var promoStartMonth = start.slice( 0,2 ).replace("/", "");
    var promoStartDay = start.slice( start.indexOf("/"), start.length ).replace("/", "");
    var promoEndMonth = end.slice( 0,2 ).replace("/", "");
    var promoEndDay = end.slice( end.indexOf("/"), end.length ).replace("/", "");

    var myPromoStart = new Date( currYear, promoStartMonth-1, promoStartDay);
    var myPromoEnd = new Date( currYear, promoEndMonth-1, promoEndDay);

    if ( ( ( d > myPromoStart ) && ( d < myPromoEnd) ) || ( d >= myPromoEnd ) ) 
    {
        objData = obj[i];
        console.log(obj[i]);
    } 
}
```

My Date Range is stored in a json and it looks like this.

```
"dateRange" : [ "4/13", "5/12" ],...
```

---

Im not sure how else to do this as I have tried many different ways and nothing seems to be working accordingly.

Comment: what is this for? ( d >= myPromoEnd )

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what the data object actually looks like, the "JSON" is not valid.

You seem to have made a good start, but are getting lost in converting the range to dates.

```
var objData = [];
var month = [ "january","february","march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "October", "november", "december"];
```

The *month* variable isn't used, so it's not necessary. The next part seems OK:

```
var d = new Date( );
var currDate = d.getDate();
var currMonth = d.getMonth();
var currYear = d.getFullYear();
var currPromoIndex;

for (var i =0; i < obj.length; i++) {
```

I'll assume that `obj[i].dateRange` is `["4/13", "5/12"]`.

```
    var start = obj[i].dateRange[0];
    var end = obj[i].dateRange[1];
    var promoStartMonth = start.slice( 0,2 ).replace("/", "");
    var promoStartDay = start.slice( start.indexOf("/"), start.length ).replace("/", "");
```

Extracting the month and day from the range values is simpler if you use a regular expression and *split*:

```
    var start = obj[i].dateRange[0].split(/\D/);
    var end = obj[i].dateRange[1].split(/\D/);
    var promoStartMonth = start[0];
    var promoStartDay = start[1];
    var promoEndMonth = end[0];
    var promoEndDay = end[1];
```

The next bit is OK:

```
    var myPromoStart = new Date( currYear, promoStartMonth-1, promoStartDay);
    var myPromoEnd = new Date( currYear, promoEndMonth-1, promoEndDay);
```

But the logic here is flawed (and has too many parenthesis for easy reading):

```
    if (((d > myPromoStart) && (d < myPromoEnd)) || (d >= myPromoEnd)) {
```

Why the `||`? That will include all dates after *myPromoEnd*. If you want the range to include the end dates, then use (and remove most of the parenthesis):

```
    if (d >= myPromoStart && d <= myPromoEnd) {
```

And then you have an issue with:

```
        objData = obj[i];
```

That replaces the value of *objData* with *obj[i]*, you probably want to add it to the array, so:

```
        objData.push(obj[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for `for (var i =0; i < Object.keys(obj).length ; i++)`
You cant get the size of an object just using `.length`.
and what RobG said, you need to use .push() to add an object to the array.
Hope this help:

https://jsfiddle.net/geradrum/c2xkntsh/

Comment: These are both great answers but for some reason once it gets to december it breaks

Comment: here is my complete json
'"promotions":
 [
  
  {
   "id": "winter",
   "dateRange" : [ "12/1", "1/13" ],
   "title":"Cut Ahead At The Riviera",
   "desc":"providing you personalized care",
   "body": "book.php",
   "color": "#3690ce",
   "backgroundImage": "backgroundImage.svg",
   "background": "background.svg",
   "mainImage": "main.svg"
  }
 ]'
this is one example. All the other months are in the same format.